# Is there any way to block a specific language from google translate (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, desktop

I always use url bar to type **translate.google.com** and press **Tab** to quickly translate words. But in Chinese, there is `zh-CN` and `zh-TW` for translate result, and `zh-TW` is my native language.

I have try to hide the elements by Stylish extension, or block the zh-CN button by AdBlock extension. But it still randomly shows the translate result in zh-CN.

It's there any way to completely block a specific language in translate.google.com?